# Master page giving error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: deployment, custom-masterpage

So this is the scene:

We have a sharepoint site with different portals. Each portal is deployed by its seperate wsp on same server.Now there is this staging server where all of us deploy our wsps for testing.Yesterday under some circumstances, many of the wsps got reployed(we are yet to figure out that). and our portal started giving error. When we turned on the custom errors, the following error was thrown

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

this are the things that we have tried, but with no luck.Also the same is working on development server.

- Redeployed the latest wsp file
- Deactivated/activated the master page feature
- Restored the Previous version of master page
- Restarted the timer job and sharepoint administration.

When we tried to manually upload the master page from DEV to staging, we got and error for AutoEventWireup="true". After removing that tag, safe control error was encountered.

When I tried to re-ghost the page, it did not allowed me to Reset to site definition, stating that the resetting to site definition is not allowed for custom pages.

I Googled on the above errors but was not much successful.

quick help will be much appriciated.

This is the detailed ULS log entry

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at AAES.DM.Helper.Utilities..ctor() at AAES.DM.SharePoint.Masterpages.DM.MasterPages.AAESDMmaster.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was not master page but web.config of the web application. db connection details were deleted from the app settings section and master page had the code for authentication the users on page load, hence the object refrence error ; as it was not able to reach to db.

Answer (score 0):

Explore uls logs. Call stack will be very helpfull to find error source.

Comment: checked that already. Added the uls log entry in my question

Comment: Tyagi thanks for providing call stack - it's very helpfull.
You use third party or hand made component from namespace AAES. Constructor of AAES.DM.Helper.Utilities class throws exception. It could be helpful to see source code of this constructor. If it is not your code you can use some reflector.